# Anchor or button

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What element should I use for JavaScript actions?

Actions that does something like play/pause/stop/new/open/save/print/close, etc.

```
<a id="play" href="#">Play</a>
<a href="#play">Play</a>
<button id="play" tabindex="0">Play</button>
<div id="play" role="button" tabindex="0">Play</div>
```

I see many people use anchors `<a>` with a `href="#"` but that doesn't feel very semantic, it feels like anchors are for hyperlinks that point to a resource, not for actions that does stuff. Then you have to hack it around with `event.preventDefault` (i.e. `return false`).

I rarely see people use the `<button>` element, but isn't it what is supposed to be used?

Comment: Your suspicions about links are 100% correct.

Comment: If the default styling for the `button` element is considered undesired when using a icon to symbolize the action, it can be overriden with a CSS class. `.btn-icon {background: none; border: none}`

Comment: Who cares what everyone else does? If buttons work for you, and work well, use them!

Comment: In programming, there is at least two ways to do almost everything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TLDR; you can open an anchor link in a new Tab/Window but not a button.

Here is a rule of thumb:

- For navigation just use **anchor** it's alright to style it as a
  button and let it use it's `href` attribute well.
- For quick actions (play,pause,stop,+1 like) just use **button** it
  doesn't have `href` for a reason!

Consider this code.

```js
const [anchor] = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
const [button] = document.getElementsByTagName('button')

anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('anchor clicked')
  e.preventDefault()

}, false)

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('button clicked')
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2px;
}


button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#">
  Anchor
</a>

<hr/>

<button class="btn" type="button">
  Button
</button>
```

**Styling**

They both look almost alike (with minimal justifications) the only problem is that you'll have to undo some stylings that come with `button` like `border` & `background` but with anchor you don't get the clicking popping animation that you'd get with button.

**Functionality**

But since the anchors `<a>` need `<a href="some/path">` to work *even if it's just `#`*, unless you need to navigate after clicking the anchor you'll have to use `e.preventDefault()` in your javascript to prevent it.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to decide which element has the best semantics for a JS based user interaction is to ask what you want to happen if the JS fails ([which it will](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Think [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Think [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Should the user just go to another page? Use a link. The `href` will be the fallback from when the JS fails.

Should the user go to another page while sending some data or making a POST request? Use a button, put it in a form.

Is it impossible to have any kind of server fallback? Use a `<button type="button">` and consider generating it from JS/DOM instead of HTML.

Comment: Here's a neat exploration of the pros and cons of each: <https://bitsofco.de/anchors-vs-buttons/>. It suggests using anchors for fallback, and then replacing them with buttons in JavaScript. Best of both worlds: progressively enhancive and semantically correct.

Answer (score -3):

> Then you have to hack it around with event.preventDefault

You could set the href to `javascript:void(0)` rather than #, which would prevent execution without having to use `event.preventDefault()`

But buttons are probably better for this sort of thing

Comment: I have heard that using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in the `href` attribute is not advisable. The `href` attribute is for hyperlinks.

Answer (score -5):

This is more of a preference thing.

Personally, I prefer to either use the <button> tag or make my own.

If it makes more sense to you to use the <button> tag, use it. If it works, it's not wrong. =)

Comment: I noticed that Gmail uses `div` elements, while YouTube use `button` elements. Google.com use `a` and `div` elements.